# Possible to download all versions of a document?

Tags: document-library, backup, versioning, version-history

My team is looking for a way to download all versions of a particular document on our site (or more generally we would like to back-up all versions of all documents in a particular document library).  Is there a simple method to do this?  My team does not have access to the server they are housed on, although I can navigate to the library by `\\sharepoint.company.com\oursite\Library Name\` in windows explorer (I can't find past versions from here).

If possible, a solution that is not programmatic would be best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal export options to export a document library to disk, including all of the previous versions of documents in that library. Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx

```
Export-SPWeb -IncludeVersions All
```

If you need all the documents downloaded as documents, you'd need a way to change all the filenames to provide unique names. You can get there with Powershell as well, although that might be considered a programmatic solution I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Imho there is no non-programmatically method to do it. If You have access to server, You can use powershell like Jasper already answered, example of function is [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95073/powershell-for-downloading-documents-with-versions).

But without access on host server you will need to use web-services, and most likely you meet permissions problem again there.