# Export SharePoint 2007 Library files with metadata into physical location

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-library

We have one requirement we want to extract around **100GB data from SharePoint 2007 library files and metadata** into physical location.

If any interruption while downloading files we have to resume from that scratch.

Since it is **SP 2007 we are unable to move with PowerShell/ CSOM**.

My Idea would be console application, Please suggest me if any other options to accomplish this task.

What I have tried:

Investigated with CSOM and PowerShell approaches but using both the approaches we are unable to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell,you can create backup or template file using Export object.

So here is Approaches,

1. Using PowerShell/CSOM/SOM: Get Library object and iterate each items property, insert in csv and download linked files.
2. Using Hybrid(PowerShell+OOTB):It will save your time, Download files using PowerShell and then using "Export to Excel" option given in Library ribbon.
   [image]
3. Use 3rd party Applications like ShareGate or [this](http://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-to-fileshare-migration/splistx/features).

Comment: Hi anil pal, using Export Excel in ribbon it exports the latest version only but we need all versions.

Comment: Using Export Excel, u will get excel of library. for documents and previous versions use powershell

Comment: check out  [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95073/powershell-for-downloading-documents-with-versions)

Comment: hi anil, i just updated my question i request you to kindly recheck and provide your valuable comments on the same.

Comment: just for information, do you want backup(.bak or .cmp) or file hierarchy to be downloaded?

Comment: Hi anil, back up is not a mandatory but if possible we can get the back up first, because while exporting time files may corrupt naaa. Any how I visited the below site you just confirm me whether this will help me to connect webservice and retrieve the library files with metadata. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmyancs/2007/09/14/how-to-download-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-library-remotely-via-lists-asmx-webservice-sps-2003-moss-2007/

Comment: Yes webservice will help you and it's possible to get versions and metadata of list

Comment: since all versions will have same name, so at the time of downloading rename doecuments

Comment: user (siteurl)/_vti_bin/Versions.asmx for versions